# What is the proper use of "informed that"

Tags: word-usage

Is the following a proper use of the phrase "informed that?"

"He informed that he is sleeping better."

Comment: It would sound better with an object. E.g. "He informed us that he is sleeping better". In future, try to explain your exact doubts to the community. Without adding specific doubts, your question might be viewed as needing proof-reading, which is considered off-topic here. More info available in the [help centre](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 1):

I doesn't really work in your example. Probably using "said" is enough.

> He **said** that he is sleeping better.

But you could have an example like:

> He **was informed that** he passed the test.

In this usage of *informed that*, informed will be intransitive, since an object will come between *informed* and *that*.